# Overflow:hidden; retaining content width but hiding content: Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, overflow

These [t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727083/overflowhidden-not-working-as-expected-in-google-chrome)h[r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425460/chrome-and-overflowhidden-issue)e[e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128139/can-overflowhidden-affect-layout) SO questions didn't quite get me what I needed, interesting though the BFC layout stuff was. ([One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727083/overflowhidden-not-working-as-expected-in-google-chrome), [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425460/chrome-and-overflowhidden-issue), [Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128139/can-overflowhidden-affect-layout))

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpA3V/2/) shows the issue I'm having, only in Chrome is the hidden content still enforcing width dimensions of the div classed 'content' with a width value of 0px.

This layout is the basis for an Accordion style menu... which obviously isn't going to work if the enforced content dimensions are visible :P

Why is Chrome behaving this way, maybe I missed something in the BFC explanation? A solution would be awesome.

Comment: As far as I can tell Chrome is doing it correctly. You are setting a width of 0px on the content class. The overflow attribute merely means that you don't want the text content to be visible outside the bounds (of 0px width). If you set it to 5px wide you would see a part of the 'C' in 'CONTENT.' And the 5px would be the width. Which is correct. Right?

Comment: [for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727083/overflowhidden-not-working-as-expected-in-google-chrome) [your](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425460/chrome-and-overflowhidden-issue) [convenience](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128139/can-overflowhidden-affect-layout) (I'm sorry, but trying to click a single letter with a 1900+ resolution is so annoying)

Comment: @Marshall Actually i think Chrome is doing it wrong. As the `overflow: hidden` is giving it a width bigger than the width of the content `0px`. If that is the case I wouldn't rely on it staying that way.

Comment: @Joseph - o_O thee's nothing interactive happening in my fiddle. I'm showing you the overflow:hidden; strangemess, not a fully functional accordion menu - is that not clear?. +James & +Marshall - that is interesting... 1px would almost do it for me... but it does seem that Chrome is doing it wrong based on 0px. +Joseph... oooh, sorry the SO questions not the fiddle, sorry :P

Comment: @galchen: I initially had display:none; however at the point where I will be tweening from 0px - Xpx will it not have bizarre effects, given that to do the tween I will be changing display:none; back to display:block; ? Also, display:none; is going to introduce difficulties with font replacement on content that needs to be hidden on page load...

Comment: well it really depends on which div's size you are changing. you could change the outer (class=slide) in that case you can set any size in pixels. the chrome issue is that it does not allow with 0px. if you put 1px it will work. to make a smooth slide, make it go all the way to 1 and then display: none

Comment: Mmm, I think that will have to do galchen. I'll leave the Q open for a bit but feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a nasty bug!

Need to research if further, but if you know the original width of `.content`, then you can add the same negative margin to it: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/cpA3V/7/ — so it would compensate the original width. And if you'll need to animate the accordion, you'll just need to animate the `margin` alongside the `width`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
.slide {
    float:left;
    width:25px; /* width added here (same width of '.handle' ) */
}
```

Example : [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpA3V/5/)

Answer (score 0):

If you give the `.content` a width of 1px, then it behaves correctly. I can't explain what's happening but you can solve this by using `display: none` instead of the width.