# Issue with overflow:hidden on mouseover in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

Here is a jsfiddle illustrating my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/snorthway/TP55F/6/

It works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome if you mouse over, the blue div suddenly overflows the circle and stays that way on mouse out. All I'm doing on mouse over is adding a class to make the colors brighter.

I tried putting `!important` on `overflow:hidden`, to no avail. I also tried doing `position:relative` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12446396/1763621). I put both of those things in the `.hov` class (which gets added on mouse over and removed on mouse out) as well, still nothing.

Another weird thing is that if I inspect element in Chrome, it goes back to normal. As in, if I have the inspector open, mouse over the circle, then move my mouse anywhere into the inspector, the overflow disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `overflow: hidden;` in the `.incomplete` style definition.